# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a page coded in React with NextJS hooks, when I try to render a page the error says what's in the title, I presume because the object which I'm mapping is empty/undefined on first load. I added "?" to every map I have on the page and it's still giving me this error... I noticed that if I stay on that page after it gives me error and press "Ctrl + shift + r" the page loads normally. What could be causing this?

```
import {Fragment, useEffect} from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import DashboardPage from "../../../../components/components/dashboard/DashboardPage";
import LayoutDashboard from "../../../../components/layout/LayoutDashboard";
import React from "react";
import Pusher from "pusher-js";
import useSWR, {mutate} from "swr";

const fetcher = async () => {
  const response1 = await fetch("API");
  const data1 = await response1.json();


  const props = {
    data: data1,
  };
  return props;
};

export default function Dashboard(props) {
  const {data, error} = useSWR("data", fetcher);

  useEffect(() => {
    //Pusher.logToConsole = true;
    var pusher = new Pusher("pshr", {
      cluster: "eu",
    });
    const channel = pusher.subscribe("chnl");
    channel.bind("chnl", function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      mutate("data");
    });
  }, []);

  if (error) return "Error";
  if (!data) return "Loading";

  console.log(data);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>Dashboard</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
       
      </Head>

      <LayoutDashboard restaurantData={props?.restaurantData[0]}>
        <DashboardPage
          orders={data?.showItemsOnOrder}
          dashboardCards={data?.dashboardCardInfo}
          ordersGraph={data?.dashboardGraph}
        />
      </LayoutDashboard>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const response = await fetch(`API`);
  const data = await response.json();

  const tables = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= data[0].restaurantTables; i++) {
    tables.push({
      restaurant: data[0].queryName,
      tableNr: i.toString(),
    });
  }

  return {
    paths: tables.map((table) => {
      return {
        params: {
          restaurantName: table.restaurant,
          tableNr: table.tableNr,
        },
      };
    }),
    fallback: false,
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const response = await fetch(`API`);
  const data = await response.json();

  return {
    props: {
      restaurantData: data,
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
}
```

**EDIT**
I recognized that the site works normally if I go straight to the link that I want... It stops working when I'm calling components with **Link** tags in nextJS then it throws an error that it's in title... So if I go straight to the link everything works as expected maybe that is also the reason that the page works if I click on my link and then refresh it... So what could be the problem with **Link** tag? This is my code for it:

```
<Link
       href={{
              pathname: "/restaurant/restaurantName/dashboard/",
              query: {restaurantName: restaurantName},
            }}
          >
            <div
              className={
                router.pathname == "/restaurant/[restaurantName]/dashboard"
                  ? "text-blue-600 bg-gray-50"
                  : "text-gray-700 "
              }
            >
              <div className="flex p-3  space-x-4 0 hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-blue-600  cursor-pointer">
                <DonutLargeIcon className=" text-gray-300" />
                <p className="">Dashbord</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Link>
```

Comment: I think the error has to do with `data[0]` being `undefined`... check that your API request is working properly and giving you data you expect.

Comment: In your `fetcher` function you're returning the data as `{ data: data1 }`, meaning if you want to access the actual API data returned by `useSWR` you need to access `data.data` not just `data`.

Comment: @JacobLockwood Yes API request is working as expected since after the hard reload the page works normally...

Comment: @juliomalves but why does the page work after the reload and not on the first load?

Comment: Do you still see the same issue if you fix the issue I mentioned?

Comment: I still see the same issue because data.data has no values... The data without the .data does in fact have its values but just not if I render a page via NextJS Link hook. But if I render the page via direct link of the page everything works...

Answer (score 1):

1-if data is undefined on the first component render I think this approach will work

- first-time data is undefined
- sec time data is fetched then u can use as below

```
const fetcher = async () => {
  const response1 = await fetch("API");
  const data1 = await response1.json();


  const props = {
    data: data1,
  };
  return props;
};
```

- if look at ur fetching function u `return props= {data: data1}`
- `const {data} =useSWR("data",fetching)` it should be data.data.showItemOnOrder

```
return (
    <Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>Dashboard</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
       
      </Head>

      <LayoutDashboard restaurantData={props?.restaurantData[0]}>
       {data&& <DashboardPage
          orders={data.data.showItemsOnOrder}
          dashboardCards={data.data.dashboardCardInfo}
          ordersGraph={data.data.dashboardGraph}
        />}
      </LayoutDashboard>
    </Fragment>
  );
```

Comment: Sorry but how is your code different than mine? It looks the same to me...

Comment: can you show me the console.log(data) from useSWR ? It's caused by your access object properties incorrectly

Comment: The data is correct... The page works after reload every time so there seems to be the problem with getting to page in the first attempt

Answer (score 0):

Your useEffect needs `data` in it's dependency array for it to trigger a rerender based on `data`. Also, you'll need `if (!data) return` at the top of this useEffect to prevent the error.

So:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //Pusher.logToConsole = true;
    if (!data) return

    var pusher = new Pusher("pshr", {
      cluster: "eu",
    });

    const channel = pusher.subscribe("chnl");

    channel.bind("chnl", function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      mutate("data");
    });
  }, [data]);
```

Comment: I copied your code and replaced my useEffect with your code, the issue is still the same...
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Answer (score 0):

> What could be causing this?

The `data` is undefined in your function `getStaticPaths`.

```js
  export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const response = await fetch(`API`);
    const data = await response.json(); // <-- here, your data is undefined
```

Now I don't use `fetch`, but I think it doesn't throw in case of 4xx or 4xx errors. *Checking MDN* yes, you need to check if the response is actually OK. Something like this:

```js
  export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const response = await fetch(`API`);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not OK');
    }

    const data = await response.json(); // <-- now this won't be undefined
```

You can read more about this behavior here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful

**EDIT** Sorry, I have just noticed that you also reference `props?.restaurantData[0]`.

So instead of `<LayoutDashboard restaurantData={props?.restaurantData[0]}>` use `<LayoutDashboard restaurantData={props?.restaurantData ? props?.restaurantData[0] : undefined}>` like here:

```js
<LayoutDashboard restaurantData={props?.restaurantData ? props.restaurantData[0] : undefined}>
  <DashboardPage
    orders={data?.showItemsOnOrder}
    dashboardCards={data?.dashboardCardInfo}
    ordersGraph={data?.dashboardGraph}
  />
</LayoutDashboard>
```

That's because, by putting an optional chaining operator (`?`) after `props`, you only try to read `restaurantData` if `props` is not undefined. But since it's not, then you try to access the first element in `restaurantData` by using `restaurantData[0]` without checking if `restaurantData` is actually defined.

Check that the `restaurantData` is defined and access `restaurantData[0]` only if it's defined.

Comment: I added your piece to my code and the issue is still the same...
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: @Floky99 Can you confirm that the API call in `getStaticPaths` returns valid JSON when this error happens?

Comment: @Floky99 I think I know what caused it, see my edit.

Comment: I can confirm that the data from JSON is returned and it's valid since after the hard refresh shows up my page normally after error is shown on page... I also tried to add your edited code to my project and the problem still persists...

Comment: The problem lies in the fetching of the data for components nested in <DashboardPage/> because if I remove this component site works normally since props are fetched server side so first render doesn't have a problem with that, the problem is something with SWR fetching even tho I'm checking for if(!data) return loading...

Comment: @Floky99 you should have a stack trace printed in the console when the error occurs. Can you post that as well?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at DashboardPage (DashboardPage.js:28)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)`

Comment: `at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293)
    at react-dom.development.js:11327
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11322)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11309)`

Comment: `at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21893)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:25482)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:26037)
    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:26103)
    at renderReactElement (index.js:483)
    at doRender (index.js:665)
    at _callee2$ (index.js:375)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:294)
    at Generator.next (runtime.js:119)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (index.js:28)
 at _next (index.js:46)
    at index.js:51
    at new Promise (<anonymous`

Comment: `at index.js:43
    at render (index.js:396)
    at Router.subscription [as sub] (index.js:334)
    at Router.notify (router.js:1060)
    at Router.set (router.js:878)
    at Router._callee$ (router.js:730)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:294)
    at Generator.next (runtime.js:119)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25)`

Comment: @Floky99 and what is at `DashboardPage.js:28` ?

Comment: `function DashboardPage(props) {
  const [thisMonthOrders, setThisMonthOrders] = useState(
    props?.dashboardCards[0]?.orders?.thisMonth[0]?.orders //line 28
  );`

Comment: @Floky99 so how do you expect to find the solution if you have posted an irrelevant part of the code? Also, you need to update the question with these new informations, not add them to some comments noone is likely to ever read,

Answer (score 0):

For someone who has tried get data from array inside an object and got this error - you can try to check with `length` like this way:

```
object?.array.length ? object?.array?.someItem![0] : 'not exist'
```

Take attention that we check with chaining sign (`[?]`) and logical NOT (`!`)  for more safe search.